# CSS Fixed Position float right

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<style> 
        .floatright 
        {
            float: right;
            margin-right:800px;
        }

        .menu {
            padding: 0;
            float: right;
            width: auto;
            position:relative;
        }
        .menu ul {
            list-style-type: none; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 0;
        } 
        .menu li { 
            display:inline; 
            padding:0;
            margin: 0px;
        } 
        .menu a:link, 
        .menu a:hover {
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:0 5px 5px 0;
            margin-right: 8px;
        }
</style>

<div class="floatright">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="/apidocs">api</a></li>
<li><a href="/tools">tools</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

it is meant to float to the right of the page (not in the right corner - just to the left) and have gaps between each link.

The gaps work ok but when the screen is resized ti does not stay where it is supposed to

any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Charlie, because you have a 800px margin on the right of the div it will always have that margin regardless of the screen resolution.

If you're wanting the margin to become less based on screen resolution maybe look at using percentages or media queries.

Comment: I have tried changing this to 25%, auto and tried removing it completely but still the same issue.

The links i need to have on top of something that displays in the middle of the page and then if the screen res is smaller on another PC it stays on top of the other object rather than moving with the screen

Comment: To get this straight - you want the links to sit in the center of the page? Do you want them stacked on top of each other or side by side?

Then when the window gets smaller you want them to stay in the middle of the page?

Comment: thats pretty much it. the website is flx.im - the links to the right of page at the top (api / tools / blog) need to be just above the orange box to the right of it and then when the page is resized or the users screen is smaller the links need to stay just above the orange box to the right

Comment: Take a look at this quick Fiddle I've created for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/vVqua/

I've changed your css abit and changed the HTML so you may want to adjust it a little.

Also, might be worth getting rid of the images for the borders and other features. That'll enable you build something responsive to the window size easier.

Comment: @micp you really got to the same answer as me. But you would want the parent container to be set to a fixed width ... not 100%. Like I propose in my answer, or I changed here in micp's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6mnP/

Comment: @MartinTurjak yeah I set it as 100% to demonstrate what would happen if you changed the window size because he mentioned he wanted the links to sit in the same place if you changed the viewport.

Maybe should of explained that a little better in my reply! Thanks for picking up on it.

Answer (score 2):

wou need to center the parent div ...and then the menu will float right.

```
    .floatright {
        width:1000px;
        height:50px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Where the width should be the width of the "orange box".
The menu already floats well in its parent div.

here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hvLkh/

**Additional advice:** 1) do not put divs outside the body tags, 2) add a hight attribute to the div to push the box down, and 3) add the font formatting straight into your css and avoid font tags ... like this:

```
    .floatright {
        width:1000px;
        height:50px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Arial,Verdana,Tahoma;

    }
```

And here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6mnP/1/

Comment: and there should not be any additional level of tags (that are not floated right) between the centered and floated right menu.. I just saw on your page that you added a font tag ... that prevents the menu from floating right.